# Prepositions: "in" vs. "on" a tab/widget

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage

In my quest to grasp the dichotomy between "on" and "in" I have found another example that left me in doubt.

> 1. Initializes the widgets added on the tabs.
> 2. Validates the information on the widgets.

At the first example I think the widget is being added **in** / **into** the tab.
As far as the second example once again I think the information is validated **in** the widget not on the widget because the information is inside the widget.

Could you help me here clarifying this ?

**Note**: If you are not familiar with the concept of tab and widget you can check it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget).

Comment: I would suggest 'onto' the tabs makes for a better sentence. And i would agree with you that, as the widgets are sentient-ish entities (they probably process data) their internals are referenced by the preposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although a tab is technically a specific type of container element which you would think calls for "in" as the preferred preposition, the usage metaphor treats it as a sheet of paper, ONto which things are placed or written.  A widget, although also a container element, is a more generic term; thus it is treated as an undifferentiated container, and then the metaphor clearly calls for things to be placed INto it.

Answer (score 2):

The inherent problem here is drawing the line between the real world and the online world. Some people are hesitant to make a distinction that implies that something that is otherwise virtual would be an element of the real world.

However, information is described using *in* when it occurs inside of an object. *On* is used to refer to information that is clearly visible on the exterior of an object.

*Added on* may refer to extending the functionality of the tabs.  For instance, a synonym of *add-on* when referring to a software program would be an *extension*.

If the widgets are clearly visible, and appear or extend the exterior of the tabs, then they would be added on to the tabs. If the widgets appear in *the center* of the tabs, you could say that have been added into the tabs, as a sort of inlay.