# Correct preposition for information in/on/under/at a tab or different page

Tags: prepositions

I've read [Prepositions: “in” vs. “on” a tab/widget](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74791/prepositions-in-vs-on-a-tab-widget), but it asks about widgets and I am not sure if the answers apply to more general information.

For example:

> You can access the details __ the Administration tab.
>
> You should check your doubt __ our FAQ page.

My intuition says “on”, but English is not my first language. And I am not sure about the use of onto or into in this context.

Also, if anyone has a broader explanation or link  about preposition use on the web, I would be very happy to read it.

Comment: Any comments on why the downvote? At least it would be nice to know what did I do wrong...

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ika, I agree that down voting a first question without comment is bad style. While it wasn't me, my other comment might give you an indication to why someone would down vote. You could improve your question by citing relevant dictionary entries for the two prepositions.

Comment: I don't see how the linked question fails to answer your question; it, and its accepted answer, both talk specifically about tabs.  (The accepted answer there also mentions that 'tabs' are a subset of 'containers treated like paper (which takes *on* as its preferred preposition)', and your example of 'page' clearly also falls into that category, so *on* is the natural preposition to use for both 'tab' and 'page'.)

Comment: Loosely related:  [Difference between “at” and “in” when specifying location](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/87306/26083) and [What’s the difference between “in” and “at” when used before a Location/Site/Country/County, etc.?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/172343/26083)

Comment: Thank you, @Helmar, I'll try to put the research in the question next time. The thing is I haven't found specific information about the use of prepositions in online resources, I wasn't sure if it depends on the country or if there are several correct ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it should be 'on' a page. I can't give you an exact reason as to why but I would presume that when you write, you write on a surface as opposed to in a container, etc.

As for the tab, I would probably say 'under'. Again, I'm not 100% sure why but it might be because the tab is almost a way of looking something up, similar to what you might do when using a glossary or contents page in a book.